# Is this grammatically correct? I have to receive my son from the school bus

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct? I have to receive my son from the school bus. The school bus drops him off at the stop and I have to receive him. But I want to use a single sentence to say this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "I have to pick my son up from the bus" or just "I have to get my son from the bus" or " I have to retrieve my son from the bus."  Receive isn't really wrong but doesn't seem right either.

Answer (score 0):

When "receive" is said of a person, it means the person comes to your home or place of business, and you treat him as a guest, perhaps offer him a beverage.

If you are going to some other place to get the person and transport him to his home or yours, you say "pick him up" or "meet him".